# Do you need any special authorization to be allowed to host a porn website?

Tags: web-hosting, legal, adult-content

Do you need any special authorization to be allowed to host a (hardcore) porn website?

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question.  OP has not specified what country the porn site would be in, what web host, what exactly is meant by "porn", or who would be giving what special authorization.  If all this information was supplied, of course, I'd vote to close as "off topic" - probably belongs on webmasters.

Comment: Well it's kind of a gray area. See http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/334/should-we-take-an-ethical-stand-on-people-asking-for-help-with-unethical-sites

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: I don't think porn sites necessarily qualify as unethical. Sure, there are a lot of spam sites that host porn, but porn is also a legitimate industry as well. In fact, it would be better to accept this type of question where the asker is actually making an effort to "follow the rules". Personally, I think the majority of the SEO companies out there are a lot shadier and have done more harm than the adult entertainment industry.

Comment: @Lese: Didn't mean to imply the site was specifically "unethical", just that some of the comments may apply here, since some people are likely to find the question in bad taste. I'm guessing none of our regular members have experience in this area - as content providers anyway ;)

Answer (score 7):

First you will need to know the laws and regulations in the country you are hosting the site and creating "the content". Minimum legal ages and so on.

Second, you need to check the T&C of your hosting provider; many will explicitly say hosting adult material is not allowed. If you are self-hosting, you should check your internet service provider since they may have certain conditions, too.

Third, if you are allowing user-generated content you will need strict controls on what gets uploaded, what to do with illegal material, and so on.

Finally, I am not a lawyer (nor do I have any experience in this area) so I suggest you seek professional advice on this kind of thing.

Comment: I think with professional web hosts it's probably split 50/50. A good number of the major web hosts exercise no censorship or editorial control over content except where required by law (e.g. child pornography of copyright infringement). DreamHost is one of them; Rackspace is another; and Amazon S3 is used by many porn sites as well. But you're right, you should always check beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need "special authorization" for hosting pornography in most cases (assuming you live in a country where pornography is legal), but you do need to ensure that you're using a web host that doesn't forbid pornography on their servers. There are plenty of web hosts that allow any legal content, so this shouldn't be a problem.

However, you may want to use the [RTA label](http://rtalabel.org) to tag your site as adults-only for filtering software. This is completely optional, as are age "verification" pages, but it's good practice to make sure that anyone entering your site knows what they're walking into.

And, of course, the standard legal requirements for hiring/managing adult actors and arranging photo/video shoots apply.

Comment: @Imari: You're right, that was a typo.